# Update changes from WinForms DataGridView to database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, sql-update

I am stuck at updating changes from datagridview back to db.

This is what i did: Is there any better solution?

Is there a way to just update it all through dataSet like it is done when you use sql queries and adapter.Update(ds);

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        OkladeNEW2Entities context = new OkladeNEW2Entities();
        IEnumerable<Results> allmlbresults;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            allmlbresults = context.AllMLBResults
            .Where(s => s.StarterHLastName == "Lester")
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.ID)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(t => new Results
            {
                ID = t.ID,
                Team = t.Team,
                StarterHLastName = t.StarterHLastName,
                Opp = t.Opp,
                StarterALastName = t.StarterALastName,
                Final = t.Final
            })
            .ToList();

            bs.DataSource = allmlbresults;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ID"].Value);
                if (ID != 0)
                {
                    AllMLBResult results = context.AllMLBResults.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == ID);
                    results.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ID"].Value);
                    results.Team = row.Cells["Team"].Value.ToString();
                    results.StarterHLastName = row.Cells["StarterHLastName"].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
            //  context.Dispose();
            button1_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }

    internal class Results
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public string StarterHLastName { get; set; }
        public string Opp { get; set; }
        public string StarterALastName { get; set; }
        public string Final { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What are properties of `AllMLBResults`? Currently you are using a ViewModel, Can't you use  the entities from `context.AllMLBResults`?

Comment: I am using a view model, because ALLMLBResults have 30 properties and I want to load only few of them, and you cant use existing model for that...

Comment: It all saves nicely and automatically when I use ALLMLBResults model and select all columns...

Comment: Is this query querying local or remote database, and are more applications requesting data from this DB at the same time?

Comment: it is local db, and why does it matter?
The question is how to save changes from datagridview in a simpler way then above, if possible..